# grakn.ai installation error: Could not find or load main class ai.grakn.client.Client

Tags: java, vaticle-typedb

I've recently installed and tried to use Grakn.ai for visualization. Following the instructions on [grakn.ai's website](https://grakn.ai/pages/documentation/get-started/setup-guide.html#install-graknai), I ran into the following problem when trying to run:

`\grakn-dist-0.15.0>.\bin\grakn.sh start`

in Windows 10 command prompt, 64 bit, the following lines are displayed before exiting:

```
Starting redis
Cassandra already running
Starting engine.Error: Could not find or load main class 
ai.grakn.engine.GraknEngineServer
Error: Could not find or load main class ai.grakn.client.Client
.Error: Could not find or load main class ai.grakn.client.Client
.Error: Could not find or load main class ai.grakn.client.Client
```

I have also attempted to add `JAVA_HOME` into System Variables, however this is to no avail. (I noticed that `JAVA_HOME` did not exist when I initially looked for it and so I had to manually create the variable and set jdk path - perhaps this implies some issue)

Thank you very much for your time and I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by checking the version of the jdk you are using. Grakn requires [Oracle JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) to be specific.

Also note, that [Grakn](https://grakn.ai/) does not yet officially support Windows because of Cassandra 2.1 being beta on windows. However you **can** get it working on windows. [This](https://grakn.ai/pages/documentation/resources/grakn-on-windows.html) page suggests how you can achieve it. I would recommend going with the docker version as it is simpler to work with.